# Displaying Correct IDs for Items (for example images)[',1,2,3,']

Tags: php, pdo

I need to display Correct IDs for Items images.
I have two tables. One containing the id, title, text and image.
The first section references are correct:

```
<?php
$st = $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM `info` ");
$st->execute(array($_GET['media']));
foreach ($st as $post):
    $title = $post['title'];
    $image = $post['image'];
    $id = $post['id'];       ... ->
```

**Where the result of the image is:** example ,1, (LIKE as ',?,' etc)

Distal part of the code retrieves the image data in the second table, but not correctly according to the first reference.

```
    $pi = $post['image'];
    $statementUser = $dbh->prepare("SELECT source FROM media WHERE id LIKE ? ");
    $statementUser->execute(array($pi));
    $name=$statementUser->fetchColumn(0);
    $path = $settings['cms']['media_path'];

    # Presentation part:
    echo "<img src='$name' />";
    endforeach;
        ?>
```

According to these, database displays the picture, but as incorrect.

Can anyone help me to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:** We need, get a readable string.

**Example Function:**

```
function clean_item_str($string){
    return preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_]/', '', $string);
}
```